# How see actual return type on parametrized scala method with Intellij Idea?

Tags: scala, plugins, intellij-idea

Consider a code:

```
//here Map is scala.collection.immutable.Map
val myMap = Map.empty[String, Int]
//getting value can be anywhere, not at next line
val value = myMap.get("myKey")
```

When a press ctrl + q in Intellij Idea on `value` I see

```
Pattern: value: Option[Int]
```

But when I put cursor on `get` function it popups with message:

```
scala.collection.MapLike
def get(key: A): Option[B]
```

E.g. I need just press something on method, to see actual parametrization, not write `val some = methodCall` and inspect `val` constant.

Is there a way to see a concrete types instead of generic parametrization for scala in Intellij Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OSX if I hold `Command` whilst hovering over your method I see

```
scala.collection.MapLike
public def get(key: String): Option[Int]
```

If you're on Windows/Linux then I'm sure it's the same just with the equivalent key to `Command`.

Comment: Damn, I clicked to much quickly on it. :)